# What's it called when you switch the order of two words around?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-order

What's it called when you switch the order of two words around, completely changing their meaning?

For example, *simply childish* becomes *childishly simple*.

Or *wonderfully sarcastic* becomes *sarcastically wonderful*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a term for switching syllables of words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30800/is-there-a-term-for-switching-syllables-of-words)

Comment: @coleopterist No, this one is not a dup of the question on sybbalull switching.

Comment: @tchrist Is the answer to this one a dupe of the answer to that one? :] Wonderfully sarcastic -> sarcastic wonderfully = switching _order of two words_ around; Wonderfully sarcastic -> sarcastically wonderful = switching syllables _between two words_ (more or less).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Antimetabole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole):

> is the repetition of words in successive clauses, but in transposed grammatical order (e.g., "I know what I like, and I like what I know")

Comment: “Then you should say what you mean,” the March Hare went on.  //  “I do,” Alice hastily replied; “at least — at least I mean what I say — that’s the same thing, you know.”  //  “Not the same thing a bit!” said the Hatter.  “You might just as well say that **«I see what I eat»** is the same thing as **«I eat what I see»**!”  //  ...  //  “You might just as well say,” added the Dormouse, who seemed to be talking in his sleep, “that **«I breathe when I sleep»** is the same thing as **«I sleep when I breathe»**!”  –– http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Alice's_Adventures_in_Wonderland

Comment: You want to be careful with that; never overdo antimetabole. It can really have some serious effects on your metabolism.