# Word for when we accidentally invert the syllabic utterances of words?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

Today, during a conversation, one of my friends accidentally inverted the syllables of the word "**bookmarks**" as "markbooks." Then I immediately thought about describing **such a mistake** in speaking.

I asked my elder brother, who suggested I regard it as **stuttering**. But sadly, this word doesn't fit well for what I am asking over here, since [stuttering](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stutter) denotes the repetition of sounds pertaining to just initial consonants:

> verb
> **1.** talk with continued involuntary repetition of sounds, especially initial consonants.

See the following image about stuttering:

[image: Stuttering]

In the image above, there's talk of the word "soda", which is written as **s-s-s-s-soda** to express stuttering.

There might be a word describing the inversion of syllabic utterance of words.

> "He said 'markbooks' rather than saying 'bookmarks' because of _____ [in place of the word 'stuttering']"

The word I am asking for here can be a verb (an act of doing what I described here), or noun or noun-phrase to describe such an accidental act.

---

My question is different from "**[Is there a term for switching syllables of words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30800/is-there-a-term-for-switching-syllables-of-words)**". In that post, the OP's primary question is about the exchange of two different syllables belonging to two different words; as his first example tells "trace" and "race", which are different and both having their own distinct syllables. Whereas **my question** is about the exchange of syllables **within the same word** and without dropping any letter(s) of words e.g.:

> bookmarks > markbooks
>
> clockwise > wiseclock
>
> Textbook > booktext

Comment: Related (but French): [Verlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan).

Comment: @Glorfindel, the Wikipedia states differently about what I am asking here. As the website says "**verlan often drops the final vowel sound after the word is inverted, so femme and flic become meuf and keuf, respectively.**" // but here my question is not about dropping of any consonants or vowels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a term for switching syllables of words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30800/is-there-a-term-for-switching-syllables-of-words)

Comment: @Ahmed I see that you amended your question with clarification about what kind of switch you're asking. There's no special word to distinguish your very specific situation from the other very specific situations. Hyperbaton is for word order swaps, spoonerism is for initial sounds of words, metathesis is for any kind of otherwise unspecified swap (but usually for phonemes).

Comment: @Ahmed In your example sentence, it looks like you're searching for a speech impediment, can that be right? "He said 'markbooks' rather than 'bookmarks' because of his dyslexia." But there are no names for the specific form of dyslexia where you exchange syllables, I believe.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Any kind of switch in order, whether sounds, syllables, or words, is called:

> [metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics))

(/mɪˈtæθɪsɪs/ with accent on the second syllable).

Examples are:

- common pronunciation of 'comfortable' as 'comfterble' /ˈkʌmftərbəl/
- ['peckerwood' for 'woodpecker'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/peckerwood)

[A spoonerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) is a kind of metathesis. For example, "A well-boiled icicle" ("well-oiled bicycle").

In rhetoric, changing out of the usual word order is also called

> [hyperbaton](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/H/hyberbaton.htm)

(having numerous rhetorical synonyms like [anastrophe](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/anastrophe.htm) or [synchysis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/synchysis.htm)).

Of course 'metathesis' (not to be confused with 'metastasis' a spread of cancer to a secondary site), is a bit technical sounding. A more natural sounding alternative might simply be

> switch

or

> transposition

or as you mentioned

> inversion.

These are all mostly intentional (except for a Spoonerism). If what is happening is an actual *mistake*, then it might additionally be called euphemistically a

> [solecism](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/solecism.htm).

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but a 'peckerwood' and a 'woodpecker' are not the same thing.

Comment: @Robusto yes, though etymonline euphemistically considers them synonymous.

Comment: Reminds me of the comedian shtick of Rindercella and her gairy fodmother.

Answer (score 13):

The most common term I've heard for this is a "Spoonerism".  It's a reference to [William Archibald Spooner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Archibald_Spooner) who was known for making these kinds of utterances unintentionally.

Comment: The definition of a Spoonerism isn't ironclad, but I've typically seen it as transposing only the initial sounds of words, rather than swapping the order of compound words.  A Spoonerism of "bookmark" would be "mookbark", not "markbook".

Comment: @NuclearWang - Sorry, but no. One of Spooner's best-known malaprops is, "Pardon me, Sir, but I think you are occupewing my pie."

Comment: Spooner may or may not have spoken that way intentionally but most Spoonerisms I have heard and most of those I spoken myself have been deliberate.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'd argue that *most* Spoonerisms are made by transposing the initial sounds of two words, but you are correct that it's not the only way to make one. I'd still be hard-pressed to call "markbook" a Spoonerism, though, as it effectively reorders entire words, rather than rearranging phonemes to make new words.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a common expression, **"backasswards"** - a metathesis of *ass-backwards* - that could be used to describe this situation:

"You said that word *backasswards*, you know."

It also has other useful applications, although you don't hear it as much anymore. US.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this expression?

Comment: I've always heard it as "bass-ackwards".

Comment: @SliceThePi : me, too, but it usually just means 'completely wrong'.  Like if someone claims why something has occurred and attributes cause incorrectly.  (especially when they're assigning blame to the incorrect party)

Comment: Much as I like this idea of _backassward_ (and I very much do), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backassward) defines _backassward_ as _utterly or ridiculously backward, foolish, or wrong_ or as equivalent to [_ass-backward_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ass-backward).